# Operation on values in a hash: Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, hash

My input is:

```
aaabbbb
```

I have written the following code:

```
here = string.split(//)

 count = Hash.new(0)
 there = here.each {|a|
 count[a] += 1
}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{"a"=>3, "b"=>4}
```

Now, I want to check the number of odd values in my hash for example if my output had been:

```
{"a"=>3, "b"=>4, "c"=>3}
```

Then the answer should be:

```
2
```

Note: I am doing this to check if aaabbbb can form an anagram which could be a palindrome. So if there are more than 2 characters with odd value then it would not form a palindrome and vice-versa.

Comment: Instead of `string.split(//).each`, consider using `string.each_char`.

Comment: @Ajedi32 can you please explain why? Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Besides the obvious aesthetic reasons (it's shorter and more readable), `each_char` also doesn't create an array unnecessarily. If you do prefer to split the string into individual characters though, use [`String#chars`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chars), not `string.split(//)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `count` method.

```
count.count{|k,v| v.odd?}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values) to get an array of values. Then count the number of odd elements in it:

```
res = {"a"=>3, "b"=>4, "c"=>3}
res.values.count(&:odd?)
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using iterating over `each_value` of `count` and then `select` and then check the `length`

```
count.each_value.select { |n| n.odd? }.length
```